# Video games to learn English

Tags: vocabulary

Recommend RPG games or any PC/video games that are good to learn English?

**Mandatory requirements:**

1. Ability to replay audio
2. Double subtitles

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could play Monkey Island series. That game has some good puzzles to solve and will definitely improve your grip in English Language. But for me Tomb raider series also worked because I had to read all of the walkthrough to complete most of the game. Others could be found on web pages such as [these.](http://reallifeglobal.com/english-for-life-learn-english-with-video-games/)

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend playing [adventure games](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adventure_game). There's a lot of good old classics, like Grim Fandango and Full Throttle and Dune I and Loom and whatnot. You can both hear and read what the heroes are saying.

Still, nothing beats the book.